# Node JS 'NODE_CONFIG_DIR' not overridden on startup using babel

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, node-modules, babel-loader

I'm trying to organize some code from other developers.
The node js application is using es6 coding style and use babel to transpile the code.

when I want to implement the npm config package and set NODE_CONFIG_DIR to a specific folder the config folder is not overridden.

```
// THIS THING WORKS PERFECTLY !!!
const path = require("path");
process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = path.join(__dirname, "src", "env");

require("@babel/register");
require("core-js/stable");
require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");
require("./src/game");
```

So when I run command 'nodemon app.js' -> the output is correct

But when I tried to transfer the code inside "./src/game/index.js"
The config directory points to the default directory which is config

```
src/game/index.js

const path = require("path");
process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = path.join(__dirname, "env");

import express from "express";
```

So when I run command 'nodemon app.js' -> the output of NODE_CONFIG_DIR = /config

I want to put the process.env["NODE_CONFIG_DIR"] = path.join(__dirname, "env") on the src/game/index.js -> since later on this will be the entry point when I will compile the whole application source code